# Android - BLE bonding programmatically doesn't work on all CoolPad Note 3

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

I am using below broadcast receiver to catch bond request and bond it without user popup request.

```
private static BroadcastReceiver pairingBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int type = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, BluetoothDevice.ERROR);

                Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast type "+type, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                if (type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PIN) {
                    if(devicePin != null) {
                        CommonStuff.Log("bond pin "+devicePin);
                        Toast.makeText(context, "broadcast bond pin "+devicePin, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        byte[] pin = new byte[10];
                        try {
                            pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class)
                                    .invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, devicePin);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

                        }
                        /*for (int i=0; i< pin.length; i++) {
                            CommonStuff.Log("byte bond pin "+pin[i]);
                        }*/
                        device.setPin(pin);
                        /*if(type == BluetoothDevice.PAIRING_VARIANT_PASSKEY_CONFIRMATION || type == 1) {
                            device.setPairingConfirmation(true);
                        }*/
                        abortBroadcast();
                    }
                }
            } else if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE);

                if(state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING)
                    return;

                    if(state == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bond success",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Bond failed",  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
            }
        }
    };
```

Assume devicePin is initialized globally. This works for most of the phones. But in coolpad note 3, i got **BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT value as 1**. And when i try to bond this device using **setPin()** without considering **EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT** value, bonding fails.

Does anyone faced this same issue? Please help me to sort this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT** as 1 denotes only user can enter the passkey. But programmatically we can set the passkey using private method named  **setpasskey**.

Add below code as an else if case for type in above code

```
else if(type == 1) {
    int pin = Integer.parseInt(devicePin);
    try {
        device.getClass().getMethod("setPasskey", int.class)
                .invoke(device, pin);
        abortBroadcast();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {

    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {

    }
}
```